# Deleting your old bugs and migrating new ones

Tags: support

If you haven't noticed, a chunk of bugs have been migrated to meta.stackexchange.com and older bugs that couldn't be migrated (due to restrictions in SE system) were deleted.

There has always been a duplicate behaviour going on when it comes to support for these [bugs] thus since meta.stackexchange.com seems to be main place for this and all SE sites run the same SE 2.0 engine it would be more beneficial to you all that questions tagged [bug] should be asked at meta.stackexchange.com.

<sub>Otherwise your questions will end up dying and forgotten due to lack of activity</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Please restore them. It's not like deleting them will save any actual space, nor are they cluttering the place up.

It's going to be hard to complain to "the mother ship" that they're ignoring our bug reports if we don't have any bug reports to point them to.

Comment: That's the point.

Answer (score 1):

Folks should feel absolutely fine to just post bug reports here. Developers routinely patrol anything tagged 'bug' on any child meta site (they have a consolidated overview to find them) <strike>and act on them</strike>.

Some bugs are temporary, some are known and will be fixed in future builds, some can't be reproduced, but *all* of them are seen. I'll talk to them again about leaving a comment noting that they've at least seen the report, but please stop deleting and migrating these - it doesn't help anything and just causes more confusion.

You do *not* have to go to Meta SE if you don't want to go there, it's completely optional. Any bug or support request will be handled here in turn, or migrated there by us if it really is something that's network impacting.

Comment: +1 - wanted to add that migrating bugs that are specific to Web Applications to meta.stackexchange is counter productive. It confuses matters and is entirely unhelpful. As Tim noted, migrating them _at all_ is not necessary either - we see them, wherever they are posted. Moving them around, again, just confuses matters and can make contacting the OP more difficult. Don't do it.

Comment: I've already been told in the past by some SE staff to migrate some bugs that are specific to do with the network engine, so the whole don't migrate is absolutely vague. -1 to all of this. The fact that it took nearly two weeks to reply is quite something. Whatever yes.

Comment: How does it take over several months for one to realise they should probably comment on a bug or place a status on it that it's noted? How can as I mod know that you did in fact note a bug in your consolidated review and didn't overlook it? Not impressed by this response given the time delay on answers and acting on bugs in general. This isn't confusing because in the reference of this meta no one other than you knows that bugs are being seen. This isn't a week issue, this isn't even months. This has been something that has happened over years.

Comment: You **do** **not** have a clear procedure for bugs status notification on child metas. It's an empty support channel. Either it's quite known or one of us mods have to stick out heads in Teacher's Lounge and prod you ever few weeks. At the very least when the bug is migrated the user is given the option of community member support from other SE sites. So we can at least pretend like something is being done about it.

Comment: If developers routinely patrol child metas it certainly feels like the rounds are limited to Stack Overflow

Comment: @pnuts - why are you assuming they are being ignored?

Comment: @pnuts - I see. So, you equate no tag to it being ignored.